Linear equation form and graphing, use or normal or perpendicular vector?
Does anyone know the formula for linear equations to equal a graph with the line crossing the axis at certain points? I seem to have myself discovered the following in 2D through some trial and error and hoping someone can confirm if it accurately describes this or correct me.
#1
$Ax + By - AB = 0$
$A$ is the point crossing y axis and $B$ point crossing x axis for the line crossing as pictured below.
Does the following do the same in 3D?
$Ax + By + Cz - ABC = 0$
#2
$Cx + Dy - E = 0$
$(C,D)$ creates a line perpendicular to this one on the graph, almost like the normal vector in 3D. I haven’t figured out what $E$ does in this case.
How does this function in 3D?
$Cx + Dy + Fz - E = 0$


$Ax+By+Cz-ABC=0$ will be a plane in 3 dimensions, not a line. For a line, you need something of the form $Ax+a=By+b=Cz+c$ or a vector equation.

Thanks what do the lower case letters in the line equation specify?

That is not a simple answer in isolation. When any two of $x,y,z$ are zero the remaining lower case letters represent the point where the line crosses the $x-y$ plane (if $x=y=o$ for example).
